# Building a Linux Kernel with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio

Does anyone have step-by-step instructions on how to build a Linux kernel using Visual Studio 2010?

I've tried to search for the solution to this question directly, but no joy. A few things I have been able to find out:

1. The Linux kernel is built using the GNU C compiler, so a prerequisite would be to build a Windows GNU C compiler, in order to compile a Linux GNU C compiler. I realize the GNU C compiler source code is available from GNU.org, but has anyone actually built the GNU C compiler for Windows using the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 C/C++ compiler?
2. Once the Linux GNU C compiler is made, I can use it to build the Linux kernel, along with any other Linux-based software needed to get a Linux system up and going. This is what I got from www.linuxfromscratch.org

Some of you may be wondering why I don't simply download a pre-compiled GNU C compiler for this? The environment I'm working in is completely separated from any outside network. Even sneaker-net is not allowed. Every bit of software will have to be compiled from source, and those sources will have to be typed in by hand. It's inefficient, but it's also paranoid-secure. (Don't ask, I'm not the boss...)

Anyway, we're looking at bringing up in-house Linux boxes, but we're starting with Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010. Can someone please advise how we can turn all that re-typed source code into a working GNU C compiler for Windows? And also for Linux?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: As long as visual studio is a windows only software, I really doubt that any support for what you are trying to achive exists. The toolchain used for linux kernel is very different and probably will not be interroperable with visual studio unless you script a lot.

Comment: If you do manage to type in the source for GCC, get it compiling in VS 2010, then type in the Linux kernel source and compile it, please make a blog or a movie or something documenting this. I would really like to see it.

Comment: Your environment is that paranoid about security, yet uses Windows? That just seems...odd.

Comment: @Billy: Not trying to start a flame war...I just found it funny. Like when somebody says "Every bit of software will have to be compiled from source," but the thing running the compiler (and the compiler itself) doesn't even have the source available.

Comment: @Travis: Fair enough. (Though you have to admit looking just at your first comment it doesn't read that way...) +1 to the second comment.

Comment: You missed April 1st by 3 months and 1 day.

Comment: you can also use [sysprogs Tutorial](http://sysprogs.com/VisualKernel/tutorials/kernel)

Answer (score 7):

I think that Ken Thompson's ["Reflections on Trusting Trust" [archive]](https://web.archive.org/web/20130711144143/http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html) explains very well how futile and not paranoid enough is this idea.

> You can't trust
> code that you did not totally create
> yourself. (Especially code from
> companies that employ people like me.)
> No amount of source-level verification
> or scrutiny will protect you from
> using untrusted code.

How do you know that the compiler you are going to use to build GCC is secure if you didn't compile it yourself from source? And the compiler you used for that?

You need to type in by hand the *machine* code for a compiler to bootstrap your 100% secure environment. Only then can you trust compiled source code, whether you typed it in by hand or not.

Comment: And he should not trust hardware vendors too. +1 for the nice article.

Comment: In the post-Snowden era a comment like "You can't trust code that you did not totally create yourself. (Especially code from companies that employ people like me.)" makes me very curious.

Comment: You cant trust a computer chip you didnt fabricate yourself either, or a circuit design you didnt etch and solder yourself. There comes a limit to what is feasible not to trust and be useful.

Answer (score 5):

Fact: you need gcc to compile a kernel.

Fact: you need kernel source to compile a kernel.

Once you have those two, you can bootstrap a working kernel, targeted for any platform you wish.

You can do all this on any platform you wish.  For example, you can build a Linux kernel on Windows.  You can just as easily build a Linux kernel for ARM or PPC on Windows.

But you've got to have the kernel source and the gcc compiler to get started.

And both the kernel source as well as gcc source depend on literally thousands headers and .c files.  They're simply not practical to key in by hand.

IMHO...

Comment: Oh no I'd love to see someone type in the whole linux kernel and libc and gcc and all the stuff they depend on in by hand - that's probably the tenth circle of hell :D

Comment: @Voo: and then debug all the typing mistakes! And get back up to date with all security fixes. Muhahahahaha

Comment: You don't need GCC. clang can compile a working Linux kernel too.

Comment: Fact: You dont know what you are talking about.

Comment: http://sysprogs.com/VisualKernel/

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to build a kernel, use a Linux distribution. There is no point in building one under Windows. Even if you'll be making your own Linux, ***still*** use Linux for that.

You could always try cygwin, but I doubt that will do you much good, even if you install all the packages.

Answer (score 4):

Fabrice Bellards tcc is able to compile Linux.
It's so small you can probably compile it in Visual C++ (or modify until it works).
You could also try his qemu to simulate a computer.

Recently he even implemented a x86 virtual machine in Javascript, so you can run everything within your browser.

Answer (score 3):

> Even sneaker-net is not allowed. Every bit of software will have to be compiled from source, and those sources will have to be typed in by hand. It's inefficient, but it's also paranoid-secure.

Tell your boss that having someone type source code by hand is going to do nothing but induce bugs. If they want Linux boxes, then they're going to have to use the source code for Linux. You guys didn't type in all the Windows 7 source code by hand either, did you? The kernel is some 13.5 *million* lines of source code. There's no way you're going to be able to type that all out without inducing a ton if typo-related bugs, and that's *less secure* than just copying the source.

Your boss needs to get it through his head that even just typing that much code, even if the person in question was a 100% perfect typists, would take **years**.

Comment: I don't think typing induced bugs will be their largest problem. I think the current kernel has about 15million LOC (well do 1.5million more or less matter there?) - even letting a dozen people type those by hand will take months!

Comment: I agree. I only point that out because the op was talking about security, and typo bugs can lead to major security problems.

Comment: You could always export the typed-by-hand code outside of the security wall and diff it against known-correct code...

Comment: and besides, typing the code in by hand is still sneaker-net. A bizarro, insane sneaker-net, but still a sneaker-net :) I also wonder how much paper it would take to print out the kernel source.

Comment: @Billy Oh no I totally agree with you that this would be a major problem - but I must admit I just can't take this question very (or at all) seriously

Comment: And what would be the point of retyping anyway? Presumably it's being typed from listings that come from the files that would be sneakernetted in.  If your secure system can't safely read plain text source files (in the worst case, write a simple, easy to validate filter that verifies they're only valid C source), then I'd have to say there's not much hope...

Answer (score 1):

By typing the whole code you mean copying/retyping *every single line* of code?

Please, allow me to ask, **how different of the original code is this going to be**?

If you're **just copying**, you're **not fixing bugs nor checking possible vulnerabilities**. Are you? I'd rather spend the respective amount of time reviewing the actual code and reporting or fixing the problems you occasionaly find.

Comment: agreed. Typing the code in is no more secure than downloading it. Since you need to copy it from *some* source. If you decide not to trust that source what is gained from typing it in? You're just using a low bandwith (and high error rate) means to make the copy. If you decide to trust the source just use the downloaded source and check the md5 from the publisher.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. That is almost impossible.

How you could do it:

1. Download [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)
2. Download an [Ubuntu iso](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)
3. Install Virtualbox
4. Create and install an Ubuntu Virtual Machine
5. On that virutal machine's terminal:

> ```
> sudo apt-get build-essential
> wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.39.2.tar.bz2
> tar vxjf linux-2.6.39.2.tar.bz2
> cd linux-2.6.39.2
> make menuconfig ; make
> ```

Or something like that...

Comment: But then he'd have to type in all the binary characters of the ubuntu ISO, and type all the source for VirtualBox... that just makes the process take longer! :)

Comment: oh lol, now i read the question properly... w t f

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this question isn't a troll (is that possible?)...  Maybe you're planning to OCR the source into your system, like how PGP used to get around encryption software export restrictions.

But I don't think you'll have any luck building GCC using MSVC, regardless of how many monkeys might be typing in the source. From http://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html:

> GCC will build under Cygwin without modification; it does not build with Microsoft's C++ compiler and there are no plans to make it do so.

Of course, if you do manage to ever get GCC onto the system under the conditions you give, and you get the Linux kernel source there somehow, I think you'll run into difficulties cross compiling Linux under a Windows-based GCC cross compiler. If nothing else, the Linux source tree and build environment depend at least a little bit on the case-sensitive nature of Unix file systems (ie., they depend on the fact that fielname can differ only in the case of characters).  Windows doesn't deal well with filename that differ only by case  (I think that NTFS can be configured somehow to support them, but the Win32 subsystem will almost certainly be hopelessly confused).

I'm sure there are other hurdles.