# Android ndk kernel module compile in windows

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, linux-kernel, kernel-module

i would like to compile android lkm. my compile environment is windows. i saw many other tips for compile in linux, but no tips for windows. how could i set android.mk files ?

```
KERNELDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell    uname   -r)/build

obj-m   := sample.o

KDIR    :=  /lib/modules/$(shell    uname   -r)/build
PWD :=  $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    rm  -rf *.ko
    rm  -rf *.mod.*
    rm  -rf .*.cmd
    rm  -rf *.o
    rm  -rf .tmp_versions
```

Comment: Get Linux / Cygwin, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6561884/995891

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compile LKM, you need:

1. Linux environment (necessary, I recommend you to at least have Linux
   in a VirtualBox)
2. Android's linux kernel source code (same version
   with your target ROM or else later on you will have problem with
   Version Magic). In my case, I got HTC Nexus one with CyanogenMod
   7.2, so my kernel is 2.6.37.6-cyanogenmod
3. A GCC that was used with your kernel source code. In my case, it is Sourcery Mentor's GCC

You can check my previous question here
[Unable to compile LKM for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277542/unable-to-compile-lkm-for-android/12291635)
I provided steps and procedures to compile the LKM

Answer (score 1):

They say you only can build Android source code under Linux http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

If you went as far as recompiling the android source it would be better to have Linux

I wouldn't recommend using Cygwin, you can surely use Oracle VM Box but then why do you need Windows anyway